# Way to make a gradient for emission strength based on elevation

Tags: materials, node-editor

So through watching tutorials on YouTube I've learned how to change the colour of an object based on its Z orientation using a ColorRamp while only using one material. However, I'd like to also know if there's a way to make objects which are higher up have a lower emission strength without making loads of different materials, as I would have a lot of objects to work through.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which tutorial you followed, but you probably have something like this in your node setup. Just add an invert node between the colorramp and separate XYZ node.

[image]